# How can I mock patch for jinja2 filter in HTML?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, jinja2, werkzeug

I want to mock and patch for `url_for` method in HTML.

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='some.css') }}">
```

How can I mock patch for html? I tried to mock but cannot.

```
@mock.patch('templates.myhtml.url_for', return_value='/')
...
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error? Is the original method being called rather than your mock method?

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete error.